# How Do I Make Cuts In Mountain?

Tags: modeling

I know, super general. I am back at blender after beginner use a while back. I started working for a construction company and would like to make animations for some things that we are trying to explain in videos.

For instance, now I want to make a video of a house with a hill behind it. I built the house, sculpted the hill annnnd I am stuck. I want to make cuts into the hill I made, have them be separate objects and have the cuts be perfectly flat. Specifically, we want to walk about retaining walls. I want to animate a hill have an "L" shaped cut into it. Then another cut (which I can do after figuring out how to do the first cut) fill that second cut with "concrete" and so on and so fourth.

I believe I can figure out most of the project naturally and with tutorials but, I cannot figure out how to do these clean cuts into organic structures (where the lines are scattered randomly through hill sculpting).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you plese edit your question and add an image as example of what you want to do. It seems to me you need a boolean modifier to cut the hill.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a cube and put it inside the mountain where you want the cuts to be made. Add a boolean modifier to the mountain geometry and set the object to the cube. If it doesn't look like its doing anything you can try hiding the cube you made or setting its view type to wireframe.